# datetime striptime-replace timezone-timestamp 360sec less than timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

This is the example
If change to the 'America/New_York' timezone , there are 240 sec less.
I want to know why there is difference?

```py
transfromed=datetime.strptime(datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Shanghai')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=timezone('Asia/Shanghai')).timestamp()
normal = datetime.now().timestamp()
print(transfromed)
print(normal)
print(normal-transfromed)
```

print out:

```
1583498126.0
1583498486.620652
360.6206519603729
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you describe your issue/what are you trying to achieve and where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi, i am just confused

Answer (score 0):

datetime.now(): returns the current local date and time(according your timezone.)
So in your example you are comparing your timezone VS America or Asia(for America the difference will be 240, and for Asia will be 360) If you try with another state you will get different value....